# How to merge 2 gray-scale images in Python with OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, merge, channel

I want to merge 2 one-channel, gray-scale images with OpenCv merge method. It is the code below:

```
...
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
zeros = numpy.zeros(img_gray.shape)
merged = cv2.merge([img_gray, zeros])
...
```

The problem is that gray-scale image doesn't have depth attribute that should be 1 and merge function require the same size of images and the same depth. I get error:

```
error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/core/src/convert.cpp:296: error: (-215) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function merge
```

How can i merge this arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Solved, i had to change dtype of `img_gray` from `uint8` to `float64`

```
img_gray = numpy.float64(img_gray)
```

---

**OpenCV Version 2.4.11**

```
import numpy as np
# Load the image
img1 = cv2.imread(paths[0], cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# could also use cv2.split() but per the docs (link below) it's time consuming
# split the channels using Numpy indexing, notice it's a zero based index unlike MATLAB
b = img1[:, :, 0]
g = img1[:, :, 1]
r = img1[:, :, 2]

# to avoid overflows and truncation in turn, clip the image in [0.0, 1.0] inclusive range
b = b.astype(np.float)
b /= 255
```

*manipulate the channels ... in my case, adding Gaussian noise to blue channel ( b => b1 )*

```
b1 = b1.astype(np.float)
g = g.astype(np.float)
r = r.astype(np.float)

# gotcha : notice the parameter is an array of channels
noisy_blue = cv2.merge((b1, g, r))

# store the outcome to disk
cv2.imwrite('output/NoisyBlue.png', noisy_blue)
```

N.B.:

- Alternatively, you may also use np.double instead np.float in astype for type casting
- [Open CV Documentation Link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html?highlight=merge#image-roi)